# Bootstrap and Yii Framework

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm new to the Yii framework, and I want to get my bootstrap design in implemented with this framework.

There is a problem however regarding my custom css.

Since we have `navbar-default` for coloring the the navbar in Bootstrap.
I had changed my navbar default color with `.navbar-default{color:red;}` in my `custom.css` file.

It was fine with only bootstrap

Now when I add this to the Yii framework it gets overridden by bootstraps' default css. I use the link to the bootstrap CDN in my head of my Yii project.

Comment: Write your own `custom css` and include in **AssetBundle.php**

Comment: Load first bootstrap, then load your custom CSS sheet

Comment: yes i have included my custom.css in appasset and i have loaded cdn in my head section

Comment: Yes i solved this. I didnt knew that i can add link to Appassets. So, I just included my Bootstrap cdn link before than custom.css so that custom.css overrides Bootstrap defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a proper asset definitin in yourApp/web dir

eg:

```
    class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
    {
        public $basePath = '@webroot';
        public $baseUrl = '@web';
        public $css = [
            'css/custom.css',
        ];
        public $js = [
        ];
        public $depends = [
            'yii\web\YiiAsset',
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        ];
    }
```

and custom css places in the right dir..

this way you should have the custom.css link positioned below the bootstrap.css link

eg:

```
<title>Your Title </title>
<link href="/your_path/frontend/web/assets/bcc5353f/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 ...
<link href="/your_path/area_web_dev/catone2.0.0-dev/frontend/web/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In this way the custom.css navbar-default style should override the bootstrap style ..

Anyway if you are not able to place in correct sequence yuor uosoum.css (and be sure you don't have error in your css file) you assign the style directly in navbar widget this way (so you perform an inline style)

```
        NavBar::begin([
            'brandLabel' => $this->title = Yii::$app->name ,
            'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            ],
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'navbar-default navbar-fixed-top',
                'style' = 'color:red;',
            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i solved this.
I didnt knew that i can add link to Appassets.
So, I just included my Bootstrap cdn link before than custom.css so that custom.css overrides Bootstrap defaults.